# Can I get a specific JSON value by Id?

Tags: php, json

I would like to have the corresponding date of **typeId: 11** output from the following JSON.
The order of the typeId's is always different, so it doesn't always work, for example, to always address the second value.

```
    {
    "page": 1,
    "totalsCount": 1,
    "isLastPage": true,
    "lastPageNumber": 1,
    "firstOnPage": 1,
    "lastOnPage": 1,
    "itemsPerPage": 50,
    "entries": [
        {
            "id": 60132,
            "statusName": "GIT",
            "dates": [
                {
                    "orderId": 60132,
                    "typeId": 7,
                    "date": "2021-06-03T00:00:00+02:00"
                },
                {
                    "orderId": 60132,
                    "typeId": 11,
                    "date": "2021-05-28T00:00:00+02:00"
                },
                {
                    "orderId": 60132,
                    "typeId": 16,
                    "date": "2021-05-27T20:20:28+02:00"
                },
                {
                    "orderId": 60132,
                    "typeId": 2,
                    "date": "2021-05-27T20:19:21+02:00"
                },
                {
                    "orderId": 60132,
                    "typeId": 4,
                    "date": "2021-06-03T15:16:14+02:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With my approach so far, I don't get any result:

```
$json = file_get_contents($orders);
$arr = json_decode($orders);
foreach($arr->entries as $order => $value) {

echo '<th scope="row">' . $value->dates->[typeId='11'].date . '</th>';
}
```

Where is my mistake here?

Comment: You can't get values out of an array or object like that. You'll have to iterate through the dates to find the right property

Comment: What is $value? I would consider reviewing some previously asked questions on how to parse or iterate through a JSON Array.

Comment: Sorry - I've added the information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
<?php
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$result = array_filter(
    array_map(
        function ($record) {if($record['typeId'] == 11) return $record['date'];}, $arr['dates']
    )
);
```

use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter) to remove empty values from the result-set.

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/MPZD8)

### EDIT

With updated json information, you could use:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach($obj->entries[0]->dates as $order => $value) {
    if($value->typeId == 11) echo '<th scope="row">' . $value->date . '</th>';
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/kGqd3)

Comment: That looks good, but actually it's not working for me..

My code: https://3v4l.org/AkIcC

Comment: Thanks, you made it work! 
But one little problem within my code: 
The entries [0] only show me the value in the first order. The second order therefore does not show a delivery date. Can you show the entries in ascending order by quantity? entries [0], entries [1], entries [2] .. etc.?

Comment: Glad it works! This answers _"Can I get a specific JSON value by Id?"_. Your follow-up question, _"show the entries in ascending order by quantity"_ should be posted as a new question with your best attempt at resolving your issue and any issues you have encountered at resolving.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation i usually write a simple function like this:

```
function getDate(array $dates, $typeId) {
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        if ($date['typeId'] === $typeId) {
            return $date;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `dates` is an array you have to iterate over and filter out the proper elements by `typeId`.

Something like this:

`dates.filter(({typeId}) => typeId === 11).shift().date`

Comment: Well ... this is obviously a PHP related question and therefore this is no PHP answer.